# Jenkins reports incorrect username and password for Github credentials

Tags: jenkins

**Problem Statement:** I am getting error like "**stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.**" for Jenkins build.

My **Jenkinsfile** is as follows:

node {

```
    stage('SCM Checkout') {
        git 'https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/java-app'
    }
        stage('Compile Package'){
        // Get path of Maven Home
        def MavenHome = tool name: 'MVN_HOME', type: 'maven'
        sh "${MavenHome}/bin/mvn package"
    }
}
```

I have saved my credentials in Jenkins as below:
[image]

My Jenkins looks like below:

[image]

Unfortunately, I am getting error/log output as below:

```
Checking out git https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/java-app into /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/My-app-Jenkinspipeline@script to read Jenkinsfile
using credential githubcredentials
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/java-app # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/java-app
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Github Credentials
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/java-app +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 691f79125928ce480176fd04e96c4f61297c8051 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 691f79125928ce480176fd04e96c4f61297c8051 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Added Checkout step"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 371a72a8024ce467f287f5297efaa5662c3c5181 # timeout=10
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/My-app-Jenkinspipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (SCM Checkout)
[Pipeline] git
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/java-app # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/java-app
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/java-app +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/java-app
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:909)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1131)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1167)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/java-app +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/java-app/'

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2430)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2044)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:81)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:569)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:907)
    ... 11 more
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please assist as I want to understand why I am getting an incorrect username and password even though I can login with the same credentials to Github

Comment: It seems you have provided credentials when checking out from Jenkins console. But inside pipeline, you haven't passed any credentials.

Comment: Ok, thought that since I have provided from Console it should be inherited in Pipeline as well?

Comment: Thanks @saurabh14292 Fixed it, got it working by the below git function and arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get SCM Checkout working we need to add credentials. I did as below:

```
git changelog: false, credentialsId: 'githubcredentials', poll: false, url: 'https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/java-app'
```

Comment: Where do we need to give this?

Comment: In your groovy script Sir.